# Dynamically assign ids to divs

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have this class

```
public class Cluster {
    private int clusterId = -1;

    private DataPoint centroid;
    private ArrayList<DataPoint> points;

    private boolean selected = false;


    private float clusterPercentage = -1;
    private int clusterValue = -1;

    public Cluster(int id, DataPoint centroid) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And after my clustering algorithm finishes, it creates several clusters which are stored in an `ArrayList` like so:

```
ArrayList<Cluster> my_clusters;
my_clusters.add(new Cluster(...));
```

And all clusters have some values for their `clusterPercentage` and `clusterValue`

I'm making this interactive. So I've set up a `Tomcat Server 8` and display this model in `.jsp`

What I wan't to do is being able to print out the data that each cluster has calculated and based on that allow the user to change the `selected` variable of each cluster.

To do that, I'm iterating over the `Cluster ArrayList` and print it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < km.k; ++i) {
        %>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <p><strong>Cluster</strong> <%=cluster_id %>: <%=cluster_size%> points. <br>
                            Percentage: <%=df4.format(cluster_percentage)%> % <br>
                            Expressed value: <%=cluster_value %> <br>
                            Filter test: <%
                            if (cluster_filter) {
                                %><strong>PASS</strong><%
                            }
                            else {
                                %>FAIL<%
                            }
                            %><br><hr>
                            Sample: <%=sample_id%><br>
                            Value: <%=sample_highest_value%><br>
                            Expr. percentage: 
                            <%
                            if (sample_highscore >= threshold) {
                                %><strong><%=df4.format(sample_highscore)%> %</strong><%
                            }
                            else {
                                %><%=df4.format(sample_highscore)%> %<%
                            }
                            %>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                              <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%
        } %>
```

So my question is:

Is there a way to dynamically assign id's to my `checkbox divs` so that I will be able to know which checkbox was selected? Ofcourse, the `div's` will have to match the `clusterId`.

Comment: You should google for EL expression ;) this would be much more readable. And JSTL for the same reason

Comment: Why don't you add the `clusterId`d into the `input.value` or into the `input.id` ? This would be the best approch.

Comment: @AxelH i'm not sure I follow... can you provide the code?

Comment: Did you write this code ? Because if you don't get it, you would not be able to write this one. What do you think `<%=cluster_id %>` will do ?

Comment: @AxelH print the value of `cluster id`

Comment: so what is the difficulty `<div id='div_cluster_<%=cluster_id %>' >` will do it... or on the input : `<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox_<%=cluster_id %>' >` You are probably not yet getting the logic of when JSP is executing and when HTML is

Comment: @AxelH ok. I did that. Now i'm trying to find out how to use those ids so I can do this. 

`Model.getInstance().getClusters().get(cluster_id).select()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use same **cluster_id** to create a dynamic id for the div.

```
<div class="checkbox" id="<%=cluster_id %>_div">
```

Comment: small, simple. Give me a minute to check!

Answer (score 0):

you can put iterator number which counts the number of check boxes and append it with id(in case id).

```
 String id="cluster";
    int iterator=0;
     //put itout of your loop
//open loop here
    <div class="checkbox" id="<%=id.concat(iterator) %>_div">
   iterator++;
// close loop here
```

i hope it helps you

Comment: And how can i iterate the divs now in order to know which ones are checked?